# npm install via fabric

Tags: python, node.js, npm, npm-install, fabric

> while trying to run "npm install" with help of fabric on a server with
> Ubuntu operating system i get an error *"npm command not found"*
>
> ```
> I have installed node version v6.11.0 and npm version 3.10.10 on the server
> >  user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~$ npm -v
>    > 3.10.10
>
> > user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~$ node -v
>   > v6.11.0
>
> system information
> cloud provider: aws
> OS: 16.04 LTS
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> i have configured fabric on my local machine
>  
> Fabric versoin
>
> > > user-system@xx-xxx-xxx-xx:fab --version
>   > Fabric 1.14.0
>   > Paramiko 2.4.0
>
>
>
>  deploy():
>    require('stage', provided_by=(staging,))
>    if env.stage in ['staging']:
>       with cd(env.app_dir):
>          run(". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh")
>          run("export PATH=/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node:$PATH")
>          run("export PATH=/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/npm:$PATH")
>          run("/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/npm install")
> ```

The python code is trying to install npm with the values avialabe in package.json file

> ```
> While executing the Fab script
>
> user@ip-XX_XX_XX_XX:# fab staging:'password' deploy
>
> [server@ip] Executing task 'deploy'
>
> [server@ip] run: . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
> [server@ip] run: export PATH=/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/node:$PATH
> [server@ip] run: export PATH=/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/npm:$PATH
> [server@ip] run: /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/npm install
> [server@ip] out: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
> [server@ip] out: 
> Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 127 while executing!
>
> Requested: /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.0/bin/npm install
> Aborting.
> ```

My aim is to run the command  *npm install*  without installing node or npm as root user  but with the help of nvm which configures node for particular user rather than root.

---

Answer (score 0):

Each `run` command operates independently.  If you want to do what you are trying to do use the `prefix` context manager instead to update `PATH`.